# How to parse key values from nested dictionaries in this example?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

Please see the JSON below taken from an API.

```
my_json =

{
     "cities":[
             {
             "portland":[
                 {"more_info":[{"rank": "3", "games_played": "5"}
                 ],
            "team_name": "blazers"
            },
            {
            "cleveland":[
                 {"more_info":[{"rank": "2", "games_played": "7"}
                 ],
            "team_name": "cavaliers"
            }
    ]
}
```

I would like to create a new dictionary from this my_json with "team_name" as the key and "rank" as the value.

Like this: {'Blazers': 3, 'Cavaliers': 2, 'Bulls': 7}

I'm not sure how to accomplish this... I can return a list of cities, and I can return a list of ranks, but they end up being two separate lists with no relation, I'm not sure how to relate the two.

Any help would be appreciated (I'm also open to organizing this info in a list rather than dict if that is easier).

If I run this:

```
results_dict = {}
cities = my_json.get('cities', [])
for x in cities:
    for k,v in x.items():
        print k, v
```

it returns:

```
team_name blazers
portland [{"rank": "3", "games_played": "5"}

team_name cavaliers
cavaliers [{"rank": "2", "games_played": "7"}
```

Comment: the first question: are you sure, that your JSON is valid? it looks like nope(not all the brackets are closed.

Comment: yeah, this doesn't look like correctly formatted json.  without that, you won't be able to read it in to python (easily)

Comment: if it is not formatted correctly than that is my own mistake for trying to copy/paste.  The ACTUAL json is formatted correctly

Comment: can you update your question with correctly formatted json ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take your `cities` list and your `ranks` list and combine them, you could use `zip()` and a dictionary comprehension:

```
output = {city: rank for city, rank in zip(cities, ranks)}
```

Comment: You don't actually even need to explicitly unravel the zipped content. `dict(zip(cities, ranks))` would work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Valid JSON looks like:

```
{
    "cities":[
         {
            "portland":[
                {"more_info":
                    [{"rank": "3", "games_played": "5"}],
                "team_name":
                    "blazers"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "cleveland":[
                {"more_info":
                    [{"rank": "2", "games_played": "7"}],
                "team_name":
                    "cavaliers"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This part of code returns all you want, but I'll try to write more readable code instead of this:

```
results_dict = {}
cities = my_json.get('cities', [])
for x in cities:
    for k,v in x.items():
        for element in v:
            team = element.get('team_name', '')
            meta_data = element.get('more_info', [])
            for item in meta_data:
                rank = item.get('rank')
                results_dict.update({team: rank})

>>> results_dict
{'blazers': '3', 'cavaliers': '2'}
```

Comment: team = element.get('team_name', '')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: could you print `element`, `k`, `v` there? for better understanding of your JSON(as in question it's not valid). maybe my understanding of your structure was a little different

Comment: I updated with return values for k, v.  Will try now with element

Comment: @user5828105, your JSON is really invalid. What is that? `cavaliers [{"rank": "2", "games_played": "7"}` list without closing bracket? Just to double check if it's in a valid format, you could try: `import json;json.dumps(my_json)` . If it raises an error - it means that JSON is invalid

Answer (score 0):

What API is that? The JSON structure (if [pivanchy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34957259/674064) got it right) seems to be unnecessarily nested in lists. (Can a city have more than one team? Probably yes. Can a team have more than one rank, though?)

But just for sports, here is a gigantic dictionary comprehension to extract the data you want:

```
 { team['team_name']: team['more_info'][0]['rank']
   for ((team,),) in (
     city.values() for city in my_json['cities']
   )
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The json seemed to be missing some closing brackets. After adding them I got this:

```
my_json = {
            "cities": [
                {"portland":[
                    {"more_info":[{"rank": "3", "games_played": "5"}],"team_name": "blazers"}]},
                {"cleveland":[{"more_info":[{"rank": "2", "games_played": "7"}],"team_name": "cavaliers"}]}
                ]
        }
```

Given that structure, which is extremely nested, the following code will extract the data you want, but its very messy:

results = {}

```
for el in my_json["cities"]:  
    name = el.keys()[0]

    rank = el.values()[0][0]["more_info"][0]["rank"]

    results[name] = rank

print results
```

Which will give you:

```
{'portland': '3', 'cleveland': '2'}
```